# Cannot load mod_jk.so into server

Tags: mod-jk

when I use ajp connector with apache server and tomcat.
I did follow link: https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/ApachePlusTomcat_HowTo.html

But there is an error:

```html
httpd: Syntax error on line 424 of /opt/httpd-2.2.31/conf/httpd.conf
: Syntax error on line 3 of /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.30/conf/mod_jk.conf
: Cannot load /opt/httpd-2.2.31/modules/mod_jk.so into server
: /opt/httpd-2.2.31/modules/mod_jk.so: invalid ELF header
```

Anybody can help me. Please 
Thanks

Comment: Your mod_JK seems to be defective. Run cat mod_JK.so | hexdump -C and show us the output. Perhaps it is a zip or html file, this happens sometimes during downloads

Comment: One more question: which Linux do you use ? Did you install Apache and Tomcat using that distros package manager ? If not I suggest you change this and use a2enmod to enable mod-jk. Besides that you should consider using Apache 2.4. Please update your question accordingly. And you should copy the relevant parts of your configuration into the question because link-only questions are not very welcome on SO.

Comment: I use Sentos os and install apache + tomcat

Comment: It's called Centos. Which version ? Please remove your answer and add the details to your question, use the edit button for this. Where is the output from hexdump ?

Answer (score 0):

Apache is complaning about an invalid `.so` file:

```
: Cannot load /opt/httpd-2.2.31/modules/mod_jk.so into server 
: /opt/httpd-2.2.31/modules/mod_jk.so: invalid ELF header
```

There can be many reasons for this, perhaps you accidentally downloaded a zip file and forgot to unpack it or while downloading your browser received a html error page.

To check if your file is a valid binary you can check its content:

```
cat mod_jk.so | hexdump -C | more
```

This should return something similar to this and the magic bytes "ELF" need to be shown:
[image: Example ELF binary]

If you see `PK` or `html` this is proof for my theory I mentioned above.

Regardless of this I suggest you choose the "official" way of installing and enabling apache modules specific to CentOS. Siteloading other binaries will cause problems because modules don't match the version of Apache you use.
And if you have no specific reasons for using mod_jk you should consider switching to mod_proxy.

Comment: Hello Marged , I downloaded file mod_jk.so at link http://mirrors.viethosting.vn/apache/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/jk/binaries/windows/           ?  I think it support for windows not nilux..

Comment: my file mod_jk.so  it diff with you . Please see updating below. Can you send me mod_jk.so file right? Thanks

Comment: Can you send me this file mod_jk.so ? Please .. my email : nvtamcntt@gmail.com